# what would be a good way to implement/render a 2d tiled map for a browser game?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've made this little rpg ruby game I did while learning and now I'd like to make it into a browser game. I've already set up Sinatra framework to serve it, so what I am looking for, before everything else, is a way to represent the game map in browser (location attributes are stored in db).

The map does not need to refresh or be dynamically fetched as you scroll it, (at least at this stage of development) but, a technology which would allow me to do so in future would be a good reason for choosing it.

Things that I thought of: html tables, html5 canvas, some js framework which is designed exactly with this purpose (which I do not know of = please advice).

Yes I know about gamequery-js framework, but I've never used it, and I don't know if it's going to slow down everything down to inusability as I'm adding new features (scrolling, ajax).

I really don't know of any other alternatives.. maybe there are lighter approaches? Easier or more minimalistic ways ? More targeted js framework which is the right tool for the job? Maybe just some html canvas code, or even simple image maps, or images with absolute positioning will be enough?

The thing is I'd like to start simple, and then gradually make it better, so, as I said before, I'd prefer something that will give me room for improvement or is headed toward new web tendencies but which will also give me a bit of gratification in the beginning :)

So.. advices are needed! And appreciated! :)
Thanks

p.s. Flash is excluded because I don't like it.

**edit**: adding more techical details to better describe the map as charlietfl commented it as being too vague to give a good answer:

A new map is randomly generated by code for each new game at game start.
For now forget db, and let's say a map (say 100x100 "squares") is stored as a tridimensional array. (x,y, ...)
Last "dimension" of array stores who & what is at that map cell: a player, a building, whatever.
So all I have to do is render those "squares" or array cells to a 2d tiled map in the browser.
Hope that explains it better!

Comment: you need to do the research yourself and use what would be appropriate for your app. Nobody else can tell what you need from what little is known

Comment: I added a better description of what the map is and how it is generated to the end of the question. Please check it out.

Comment: Check out Kineticjs. http://kineticjs.com/

Comment: @charlietfl check edits.

Comment: @ppsreejith Thanks, I think you should post this an answer, not a comment.

Comment: This one is also better off in the game developer or programmer exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your terrain looks the simplest would probably just absolutely positioned images. This works especially well if your maps have a standard, tiled background. You can just use plain CSS to render the background then place terrain elements where necessary.

If you want to be fancy you can also simulate isometric projection by translating your world coordinates to HTML coordinates with a function that shifts the x coordinates along the y axis. Actually, that's not even really necessary with clever sprite and map designs.

Answer (score 1):

Do Try KineticJS, http://kineticjs.com/
According to its site,

> KineticJS is an HTML5 Canvas JavaScript framework that extends the 2d
>   context by enabling high performance event detection for desktop and
>   mobile applications.
>
> You can draw things on the stage and then add event listeners to them,
>   move them, scale them, and rotate them independently from other shapes
>   to support high performance animations and transitions.

To learn kinetic js please look at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/
Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I know for what particular reason that applies to my question you suggest kineticjs over, say, gamequery which is more popular (=more support, more tutorials...) ? Thanks

Comment: I've used kineticjs quite a bit and i must say it is extremely powerful and easy. The description of your game suggests that you need a high performance canvas framework. Well KineticJs is just that.
This might help you too, check out http://code.google.com/p/kineticjs-viewport/

Comment: Also Do check out http://www.quantumfractal.info/kineticjs/QImage-Sprite-Demo2.php for an example of a map created using kineticjs.
Hint: Use WASD to move. :)